# YearFrac in Sql 2005

Tags: sql, excel

How do I write the YearFrac function that comes with Excel in Sql 2005?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Find out the distance between two dates using [DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx), and then divide that value by 365

**EDIT**

You could, of course, create your own function to do the job:

```
create function yearfrac (@d1 datetime, @d2 datetime) returns float
as
begin
return abs(datediff(d, @d1, @d2)) / 365.00
end
```

Comment: right you are, guffa, i missed that one. in your version, though, you'd have to do something like my *365.00* solution above, to force the division to work with decimals, otherwise you'll always end up with 0.

Answer (score 3):

For the default usage (two data parameters):

```
datediff(day, date1, date2) / 360.0
```

For the special case where the third parameter has the value 3:

```
datediff(day, date1, date2) / 365.0
```

Edit:
Added a decimal to make it a floating point operation.

Comment: fyi, this truncates the return value.

Answer (score 0):

I have also created a function for this.
However when the function is applied over a large set it is better to move the function to the actual query rather then using the function.

```
/*
Yearfrac
Purpose: calculate the fraction of years between start_date and end_date
Code Actual/actual is translated from VBA code Excel formula YearFrac

Basis           Day count basis
0 or omitted    US (NASD) 30/360
1               Actual/actual
2               Actual/360
3               Actual/365
4               European 30/360
*/

ALTER FUNCTION [obm].[fn_YearFrac] 
(
                @Start_date DATE
              , @End_date   DATE
              , @Basis      INT
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(18, 10)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @YearFrac DECIMAL(18, 10)
    ;

    if @Basis = 1
        begin
            SELECT @YearFrac =
            datediff(d, @Start_date, @End_date) /
            case when -- Scenario 1: Jaar start = Jaar eind
            year(@Start_date) = year(@End_date)
            then
            a.aantal_dagen
            when -- Scenario 2: Kalenderjaar van eiddatum is 1 jaar na kalenderjaar startdatum
            year(@End_date) - year(@Start_date) = 1
            then
            b.aantal_dagen
            when -- Scenario 3: Kalenderjaar van eiddatum is meer dan 1 jaar na kalenderjaar startdatum 
            year(@End_date) - year(@Start_date) > 1
            then 
            (c.aantal_dagen/c.aantal_jaar)
            else null
            end 

            from (select @Start_date dat_start, @End_date dat_end) src
            cross apply (select cast ( COUNT(nbr_jaar) as decimal(18,10) ) aantal_dagen from dbo.dim_datum icd where icd.nbr_jaar = year(src.dat_start)) a
            cross apply (select cast ( COUNT(nbr_jaar) + 365 as decimal(18,10) ) aantal_dagen from dbo.dim_datum icd where nbr_maand = 2 and nbr_dag_in_maand = 29 and cast( dat_datum as date ) between dat_start and dat_end)  b
            cross apply (select cast ( COUNT(nbr_jaar) as decimal(18,10) ) aantal_dagen, count(distinct nbr_jaar) aantal_jaar  from dbo.dim_datum icd where nbr_jaar between year(dat_start) and year(dat_end) )  c
        end

    if @Basis = 2
        begin
            SELECT @YearFrac = DATEDIFF (d, @start_date, @end_date) / 360.00
        end

    if @Basis = 3
        begin
            SELECT @YearFrac = DATEDIFF (d, @start_date, @end_date) / 365.00
        end

RETURN
@YearFrac;
END;
```

Answer (score -3):

I know this is a little late of a response but just in case anyone else stumbles upon this here's what I've done:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.udfYearFrac
(
    @StartDate  AS DATETIME,
    @EndDate    AS DATETIME
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(18,6)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @YearFrac       AS DECIMAL(18,6)
    DECLARE @nbDaysInPeriod AS INT 
    DECLARE @nbYears        AS INT

    SELECT 
        @nbDaysInPeriod = DATEDIFF(DAY, @StartDate, @EndDate) 
        ,@nbYears = YEAR(@EndDate) - YEAR(@StartDate) + 1

    SELECT @YearFrac = @nbDaysInPeriod /
        CASE WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = YEAR(@EndDate) OR (YEAR(@EndDate)-1 = YEAR(@StartDate) AND (MONTH(@StartDate) > MONTH(@EndDate) OR MONTH(@StartDate) = MONTH(@EndDate) AND (DAY(@StartDate) >= DAY(@EndDate)))) 
        THEN
            CASE WHEN YEAR(@StartDate) = YEAR(@EndDate) AND ISDATE(CAST(YEAR(@StartDate) AS CHAR(4)) + '0229') = 1 
            THEN 366.0
            ELSE
                CASE WHEN DAY(@EndDate) = 29 AND MONTH(@EndDate) = 2
                THEN 366.0
                ELSE
                    CASE WHEN ISDATE(CAST(YEAR(@StartDate) AS CHAR(4)) + '0229') = 1
                    THEN
                        CASE WHEN (@StartDate <= cast('2/29/' + cast(YEAR(@StartDate) AS CHAR(4)) AS DATETIME) AND cast('2/29/' + cast(YEAR(@StartDate) AS CHAR(4)) AS DATETIME) <= @EndDate) 
                        THEN 366.0 
                        ELSE 365.0
                        END
                    ELSE
                        CASE WHEN ISDATE(CAST(YEAR(@EndDate) AS CHAR(4)) + '0229') = 1
                        THEN
                            CASE WHEN (@StartDate <= cast('2/29/' + cast(YEAR(@EndDate) AS CHAR(4)) AS DATETIME) AND cast('2/29/' + cast(YEAR(@EndDate) AS CHAR(4)) AS DATETIME) <= @EndDate) 
                            THEN 366.0 
                            ELSE 365.0 
                            END
                        ELSE 365.0
                        END
                    END
                END
            END
        ELSE
            ((@nbYears * 365.0) +
                (
                    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM 
                    (
                        SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY TABLE_NAME ASC) - 1) * 4 + 1900 AS [YEAR] 
                        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
                    ) yr
                    WHERE [YEAR] BETWEEN YEAR(@StartDate) AND YEAR(@EndDate) 
                )
            ) / @nbYears
        END
    RETURN @YearFrac
END
```